# Life cycle of repeatable Game Center achievements?

Tags: ios, ios8, game-center, achievements

I am trying to understand the life cycle of repeatable Game Center achievements (those that have `replayable` set in `GKAchievableDescription`) based on what (little) information there is in Apple's *[Game Center Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW13)*.

Consider e.g. a repeatable achievement "FullCircle". My assumption is that a valid sequence could consist of the following steps:

1. app calls `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:`, receives `GKAchievement` with `[achievement.identifier isEqual:@"FullCircle] && (achievement.percentComplete == 0)`
2. user finishes half circle for the first time
3. app sets `achievement.percentComplete = 50` and calls `reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:`
4. iOS Game Center app shows achievement as incomplete (sic!)
5. user finished full circle for the first time
6. app sets `achievement.percentComplete = 100` and calls `reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:`
7. iOS displays notification banner
8. iOS Game Center app shows achievement as complete
9. user finishes half circle for the second time
10. app sets `achievement.percentComplete = 50` (sic!, not: 150) and calls `reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:`
11. iOS Game Center app shows achievement as complete (sic!, because this is the second time)
12. user finished full circle for the second time
13. app sets `achievement.percentComplete = 100` (sic!, not: 200) and calls `reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:`
14. iOS displays notification banner
15. iOS Game Center app shows achievement as complete
16. `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:` still reports only one (sic!, not: two) achievements for "FullCircle"

Does this make sense or am I making any wrong assumptions in this sequence? And is there any way for inquiring from Game Center how often an achievement such as "FullCircle" was earned?